# Be G a graph and let's assume that for every sub graph G^'=(V^',E^' ) |E^' |≤2|V^' |. Show you can direct the graph edges so every exit is at most 2.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Be G a graph and let's assume that for every sub graph G'=(V',E' )  |E' |≤2|V' |Show you can direct the graph edges so every exit rank is at most 2.

So my idea was to say there exits at least one exit rank in every way we can direct such that it is >=3, then take the subgroup(of the vertices and the subgraph made from them) without the vertices with exit rank >=3 and try to get a contradiction but I'm getting stuck

Comment: Could you clarify please : "where non of without the ones which exit is bigger then 2" makes no sense. "Subgroup" what subgroup? Are they Cayley graph?

Comment: edited, hopefully it's better now

Comment: Sorry but it is still not clear (for me, sorry, could be my fault). Why are you talking about sub **groups** ?
When saying "every exit rank is at most 2", would you translate that as "Every vertex has at most 2 exit edges"? Is this what you mean by *rank*

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. I translate from another language so the terms used may not be accurate